# Translation of Canvas child not working when setting its LayoutTransform to a TranslateTransform or MatrixTransform

Tags: wpf, layouttransform

I have a simple application consisting of a Window containing a Canvas (rootCanvas).  I am trying to add another Canvas (test) to this and apply different Transforms to the child canvas's LayoutTransform.  This is all being done programmatically rather than using XAML.

Some transforms are working, whilst others are not as follows:

- When the LayoutTranform is set to a RotateTransform it works as
  expected.
- When it is set to a TranslateTransform the translation does not appear
  to be applied, and the test Canvas is still located in the top corner of
  rootCanvas
- When it is set to a MatrixTransform that has been constructed by applying a rotation and then a translation, only the rotation appears to be applied.

The code is given below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Canvas rootCanvas = (Canvas)Application.Current.Windows[0].FindName("canvas1");

        Canvas test = new Canvas();
        test.Width = 10;
        test.Height = 10;
        test.Background = Brushes.Aqua;

        // this works 
        //test.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(45);

        // this doesn't
        //test.LayoutTransform = new TranslateTransform(40, 40);

        // only the rotate part of this works
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.Rotate(45);
        matrix.Translate(40, 40);
        test.LayoutTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);

        rootCanvas.Children.Add(test);
    }
}
```

I would be extremely grateful if someone could explain what I am doing wrong here, as I do not understand why translations do not seem to be working as I would expect.

Thanks in advance,

Wibbs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please read the remarks in [FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx).

> However, LayoutTransform ignores TranslateTransform operations.

Use [UIElement.RenderTransform Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) for applying a `TranslateTransform`.

Comment: and I was certain I'd read the msdn documentation thoroughly - thanks for the speedy reply.